# Get the User Profile data with API SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have to fetch the User Profiles(selected) with filters-

```
First_Name starts with A or
Department_Name = "Test" or 
Last_Name contains A
```

and get the count of those users with API.

Can you guide me for the exact root?

Comment: Use `startsWith` with `$filter` and end-point will be `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList`

Comment: Can you please share some references, so that I can do that?

Comment: wait answering your question

Comment: check my answer if it is helpful for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `UserInformationList` for User Profile properties. Your requirement can be achieved using `$filter` operator.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=startswith(FirstName,'A') or Department eq '{Department Name}' or startswith(LastName, 'A')
```

Total count will be `response.d.results.length`.

You have to make a GET request in above end-point. For testing/exploring, you can use my [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd).

There is another end-point `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor` to get particular user profile properties by its login name.

Find more about `$filter` in my article [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: The problem with this approach is i will not return all user profiles. Only those that have participated in your target site.

Comment: That is true. `_api/search/query` has a problem also. lookup columns can not be expanded.

Comment: What lookup columns are you referring to?

Comment: `Manager` or `CreatedBy`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the search API and REST or CSOM to achieve this:

```
https://<your tenant url>/_api/search/query?querytext='FirstName=A* OR Department=Test OR LastName:A'&selectproperties='LastName,FirstName,Department'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'
```

The SourceId parameter ensures that you are searching User Profiles.